# Inter-Controller Communication in Spine.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, spine.js

Is it possible to have two controllers within the same Spine.js: Apartments and Map. Is there a way to call get the Map do do something when an Apartment is selected?

```
# Apartments
class Show extends Spine.Controller
  events:
    'click [data-type=edit]': 'edit'
    'click [data-type=back]': 'back'

  constructor: ->
    super
    @active (params) ->
      @change(params.id)

  change: (id) ->
    @item = Apartment.find(id)
    @render()

  render: ->
    @html @view('apartments/show')(@item)
    # also update the map here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have few options

## Using Routes

Use the Spine's routing to navigate to the apartment url and update the map. You can see an example on Spine's [Contacts example](https://github.com/maccman/spine.contacts/blob/master/app/controllers/contacts.sidebar.coffee#L41).

On your index.coffee define the /apartment routes:

```
@routes
      '/apartment/:id': (params) ->
        @apartmentList.active(params)
        @map.show.active(params)
```

On your sidebar/apartment list controller use the @navigate to change state

```
  change: (item) =>
    @navigate '/apartment', apartment.id
```

Finally catch the active event on your map controller ([like here](https://github.com/maccman/spine.contacts/blob/master/app/controllers/contacts.main.coffee#L13)) and update the map

## Using events

When selecting an apartment fire event

```
Spine.trigger 'selectApartment', item.id
```

and then catch this event on the Map controller:

```
Spine.bind 'selectApartment', onSelectAparmtnet
```